# React Amplify GraphQL Subscription not triggered when data changed by Lambda

Tags: reactjs, graphql, subscription, aws-amplify

I have a model configured like this:

```
type MyModel @model
    @auth(rules: [
        { allow: owner },
        { allow: private, provider: iam, operations: [read, update] }
    ])
{
    id: ID!
    someValue: Int
    otherValue: Int
}
```

and a subscription to the model:

```
const listener = API.graphql(graphqlOperation(onUpdateMyModel, {owner: user.username})).subscribe({
            next: (updatedModel) => {
                //do something
            }
        });
```

I also have a lambda that when triggered, updates `otherValue` on the model via a graphQL mutation.  This however, does not trigger the subscription listener.

I've tested that the listener picks up when the **user** updates the model and this works perfectly fine so I know the subscription is working in general.

The API is configured with the cognito user pool as the default auth.

I must be missing something here but I can't work out what.  How do I ensure my listener picks up changes made by the Lambda?

Answer (score 3):

The reason this was not working had nothing to do with the fact that it was a lambda updating the record but everything to do with the custom mutation in which it was using to update the record.

All I needed to do was ensure **all** the fields were being returned by the mutation...this includes the auto generated `createdAt` and `updatedAt`.

Comment: I should add; only all the non-nullable fields need to be returned (yes, including `createdAt` and `updatedAt`), but you can omit the optional fields.

Comment: IMPORTANTLY, if you are using Amplify's "authorization rules", you need to include the `owner` field in your response (even though it is an optional field), otherwise AppSync won't know who to send subscription-events to. If you omit `owner`, you might not get any subscription events no matter what.